# What is the differences between begin(),end() and cbegin() ,cend()?

Tags: c++, stl

Although when we traversing through begin(),end() and cbegin(),cend().
They gives us same result.But what is the difference between them?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<map>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    map<char,int>mp;
    mp['a']=200;
    mp['b'] = 100;
    mp['c']=300;
    for(auto it =mp.cbegin();it!=mp.cend();it++)
    {
        cout<<it->first<<" "<<it->second<<endl;
    }
cout<<endl;
     for(auto it =mp.begin();it!=mp.end();it++)
    {
        cout<<it->first<<" "<<it->second<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: cbegin() always return a const_iterator type, begin() may or may not -- depend on whether the caller is const or not

Comment: `mp.begin()->second = 42` would work, `mp.cbegin()->second = 42` would not. `c` is for `const`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**cbegin**: Returns a const_iterator pointing to the first element in the container.
**begin**: Returns an iterator pointing to the first element in the sequence.
**cend**: Returns a const_iterator pointing to the past-the-end element in the container.
**end**: Returns an iterator pointing to the past-the-end element in the sequence.

> http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/cbegin/
>   http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/begin/?kw=begin
>   http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/cend/
>   http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/end/?kw=end

Comment: `begin` and `end` will also return a `const_iterator` if the variable is constant.

Answer (score 9):

There are two differences, which are very much related.

The first difference is that `cbegin` has no overloads, and it is const qualified, while `begin` is overloaded by two functions one of which is const qualified and the other is not.

The second difference is in the type of the iterator that they return. As per documentation, `cbegin` returns a `const_iterator`, while one overload of `begin` return `iterator` and the other returns `const_iterator` (like `cbegin`).